# wait for a click and then autoclick a button after 500 ms in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript.

I'm writing a simple code to add it in a chrome extension call it Shortkeys.

I just want the code to make a simple action:

Wait for a click of the mouse and then click a button in certain positions of the screen after 500 ms...

This is what I have written until this moment but is not working:

```
document.addEventListener('click', TimerThenPlay);

function TimerThenPlay(e) {
    setTimeout(500) 
    document.elementFromPoint(1175, 85).click();
    stop(TimerThenPlay);
    clearTimeout(TimerThenPlay);
    return; 
};
```

What I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

I have an APP running on Chrome...

I need to Click a Link and wait 500 ms to click a button... i can do that manually but sometimes dsnt work and i have to try again..

I realize that chrome has an extension that you can inject to the page a javascript code when u press a key in your keyboard. Thats why im using Shorkeys (if u know a better extension for this, just tell me).

Well... i have assign the < key to run the code...

What i need, is that everytime that i hit the < key... Chrome waits for a click (so i have time to look for the link that i want to open with de button)...

And when i click the link, it waits 500 ms and then click the button in the position that i select ( i cant use the Button ID cause it changes every minute).

I have tried the codes above and it works for the first time.. then, i dnt know why is keeping clicking 500 ms after a make a mouse click in the next pages... How can i stop that loop in the next page?

Comment: This `document.elementFromPoint(1175, 85).click();` looks so unreliable. I wouldn't rely on specific element position. Perhaps, this element has a class or ID or at least position in DOM tree - it is better to use them.

Comment: What does your `stop` function do?

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your response... Im using it that way Cause the button i want to click change its ID every minute.. so if i assign the ID of the Button in Code, i have to change it every minute... so i realize that for what im doind is better to assign coordenates instead of the Button ID...

Comment: Hi Kamoroso... Im new into JavaScript... so.. i have searched on the internet for codes... i looked in some place that if i put Stop(function name) it will stop the function... so.. i put it on the code.. cause i need to run it once... only when i press a key in my keyboard (thats why im using shortkeys extension in chrome) to add a javascript code into a button press... if there is a better way to do it, im going to apreciate all ur help.. i need to run this urgent...

Answer (score 0):

```
function TimerThenPlay(e) {
  setTimeout(function(){
     document.elementFromPoint(1175, 85).click();
     stop(TimerThenPlay);
     clearTimeout(TimerThenPlay);
  },500)    
}
```

SetTimeout method takes two arguments. First is function to execute after second argument time passes.
Hope this helps

Comment: I have tried this.. the firts time is good.. but then is keepeing doing de same click as a loop in the next page... i dnt know why cause we r using setTimeout instead of setInterval...

Answer (score 0):

Your `setTimeout` syntax is wrong.

**Syntax of `setTimeout`:**

```
setTimeout(function(){}, time)
```

you need to update your `setTimeout` function

```
function TimerThenPlay(e) {
 setTimeout(function(){
   document.elementFromPoint(1175, 85).click();
   stop(TimerThenPlay);
   clearTimeout(TimerThenPlay);
   return;
 },500)      
};
```

Comment: Thanks.. im gonna try this... :)

Comment: I have tried this.. the firts time is good.. but then is keepeing doing de same click as a loop in the next page... i dnt know why cause we r using setTimeout instead of setInterval...